# Как убрать цифру 7 в начале строки

Tags: python, текст, логирование, minecraft

У меня есть переменная `notfullnick = logline.split('§')[5]` она оставляет после себя `7НИКЧЕЛА` так вот, как мне эту цифру 7 убрать в начале, я знаю что можно использовать `nickname = notfullnick.split('7')[1]` но если никнейм у чела `Nolik777` или типо того, то он не поймет его и просто выведет `Nolik` или ничего, как это сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: `str = '7helloworld777' print(str[1:])`

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что пользователи с такими именами тут не нужны.

Comment: @Эникейщик какая разница? Вопрос то в общем нормальный.

Comment: @Blackmeser а в чем нормальность? вопросов по типу "как удалить 1 символ из строки" тут явно не один. Да и гуглится очень просто.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin - гуглится почти всё, относительно простых вопросов тьма. Тем не менее их не закрывают под левым предлогом.

Comment: @Blackmeser если вам нравится читать здесь авторов с именами "пидорок", "хуило" и т.п. то можете их плюсовать или даже переименоваться в что-нибудь похожее. Нормальным людям такое не очень хочется видеть.

Comment: @Эникейщик нормальные люди на такое не реагируют.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать двумя способами, просто убрать первый символ:

```
nickname = notfullnick[1:];
```

или заменить первую семерку на пустоту:

```
nickname = notfullnick.replace("7", "", 1);
```